# Uniform texel buffer for Vulkan GLSL

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I have an float RGBA buffer that I want to pass to my compute shader as a Uniform Texel Buffer (for read-only access with no sampling).
Can someone tell me how to do this in GLSL?

All examples I can find seem to be skipping that topic or have a at best weak nomenclature.

Comment: FYI, if you directly look at the vulkan spec, there are examples. `samplerBuffer` is for uniform texel buffer and `imageBuffer` is for storage texel buffer.

Answer (score 4):

The descriptor type that Vulkan calls "uniform texel buffer" represents a concept that, in OpenGL parlance, is called a "[buffer texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Texture)". While normally the GLSL type for this would be `samplerBuffer`, [the Vulkan flavor of GLSL uses `textureBuffer` instead.](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/master/extensions/khr/GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl.txt)

The corresponding descriptor for this type should of course use the `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_TEXEL_BUFFER` type. However, since Vulkan doesn't share OpenGL's notion that this is some kind of texture, the descriptor's data is a `VkBufferView`, not a `VkImage` or `VkImageView`. Specifically, `VkWriteDescriptorSet::pTexelBufferView`.

Comment: Have a look set this example, it uses uniform texel buffers in compute shaders: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Vulkan-Cookbook/tree/master/Samples/Source%20Files/12%20Advanced%20Rendering%20Techniques/03-Drawing_particles_using_compute_and_graphics_pipelines

Comment: And here is the compute shader from the mentioned example: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Vulkan-Cookbook/blob/master/Samples/Data/Shaders/12%20Advanced%20Rendering%20Techniques/03%20Drawing%20particles%20using%20compute%20and%20graphics%20pipelines/shader.comp

Comment: As of 2022, according to the [GLSL 4.60 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf), uniform texel buffers should be declared in GLSL as `uniform textureBuffer` variables (see "Texture Buffers (Uniform Texel Buffers)" under section 12.2.4 "Vulkan Only: Samplers, Images, Textures, and Buffers").

Comment: @ZoëSparks: Fixed.